# How to sort list based on distance from current user returned by an async function in flutter?

Tags: sorting, flutter, asynchronous, dart

I've been trying to sort a list of objects, Here's there code:-

```
class Locations {
  final GeoPoint location;
  Locations({this.location});
}

class LocationCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  LocationCard({this.index});
  @override
  _LocationCardState createState() => _LocationCardState();
}

class _LocationCardState extends State<LocationCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Locations> locationlist = [
      Locations(location: GeoPoint(1, 2)),
      Locations(location: GeoPoint(2, 2)),
      Locations(location: GeoPoint(3, 2)),
      Locations(location: GeoPoint(4, 1))
    ]; //list to be sorted
    GeoPoint mylocation = GeoPoint(2, 2);
    double distance;
    var userindex;
    List sorted = [];

    //sort locationlist here

    for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
      if (sorted[i].location == mylocation) {
        userindex = sorted.indexOf(locationlist[i]);
      }
    }//gets user's index in list

    futureconvert() async {
      distance = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
              sorted[userindex].location.longitude,
              sorted[userindex].location.latitude,
              sorted[widget.index].location.longitude,
              sorted[widget.index].location.latitude) /
          1000;
      return distance;
    }

    return Container(
      child: Card(
        child: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
              future: futureconvert(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Text(distance.toString());
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LocationList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationListState createState() => _LocationListState();
}

class _LocationListState extends State<LocationList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Locations> locationlist = [
      Locations(location: GeoPoint(1, 2)),
      Locations(location: GeoPoint(2, 2)),
      Locations(location: GeoPoint(3, 2)),
      Locations(location: GeoPoint(4, 1))
    ]; //list to be sorted
    GeoPoint mylocation = GeoPoint(2, 2);//current user location

    List sorted = [];

    //sort locationlist here 

    return ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: sorted.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return LocationCard(index: index);
        });
  }
}
```

I need a function that sorts `locationlist` base on proximity to `mylocation`.I tried sorting using value returned by this function

```
distancef(var x, var y) async {
      return await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
          locationlist[userindex].location.longitude,
          locationlist[userindex].location.latitude,
          x,
          y);
    }
```

But it look's like I have to write my own custom sorting function because I have a future value in return.

How do I do this?

Comment: No, I've looked at that question before asking here, It didn't have a solution for my problem.

Comment: I don't understand why it does not solve your problem. As I explained there, you can't use an asynchronous callback to sort. You must await all list values first and then sort the results synchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we need the distance anyway, we can map each location to distance first. Then sort them by distance. A FutureBuilder can be used to build the ListView.

```
class LocationList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationListState createState() => _LocationListState();
}

class _LocationListState extends State<LocationList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // location list and mylocation

    Future<int> distanceFromMyLocation(Locations location) async {
      int distance = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
              mylocation.location.longitude,
              mylocation.location.latitude,
              location.location.longitude,
              location.location.latitude) /
          1000;
      return distance;
    }

    // Return a list of location and corresponding distance from user
    Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> sortByDistance(List<Locations> locationlist) async {

      // make this an empty list by intializing with []
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> locationListWithDistance = [];
  
      // associate location with distance
      for(var location in locationlist) {
        int distance = await distanceFromMyLocation(location);
        locationListWithDistance.add({
          'location': location,
          'distance': distance,
        });
      }

      // sort by distance
      locationListWithDistance.sort((a, b) {
        int d1 = a['distance'];
        int d2 = b['distance'];
        if (d1 > d2) return 1;
        else if (d1 < d2) return -1;
        else return 0;
      });

      return locationListWithDistance;
    }

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: sortByDistance(locationlist),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }

        var sorted = snapshot.data as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;

        return ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: sorted.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return LocationCard(sorted[index]);
          });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
class LocationCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> locationAndDistance;
  LocationCard({this.locationAndDistance});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Card(
        child: Center(
          // location can be accessed by locationAndDistance['location']
          // distance can be accessed by locationAndDistance['distance']
          child: Text(locationAndDistance['distance'].toString());
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I implement it in my code?

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear. Replace distanceFromMyLocation(location) with your distancef(x, y). I don't know how to extract x & y because i haven't worked with geopoint before. Then Instead of ListView.builder(), use a FutureBuilder. FutureBuilder takes a future that was returned by sortByDistance().

Comment: Hi, thanks but in ```LocationCard``` how do I sort using this, or can I get distance in```locationListWithDistance```?, and x and y are latitude and longitude from list```locationlist```

Comment: okay i hadn't seen location card. Since we already have the distance, you don't have to calculate again. I've made some edits to not remove the distance when we return which can then be used in the location card.

Comment: I've written the distanceFromLocation() function as well.

Comment: ```return locationListWithDistance.sort((a, b) { }``` has error                                       ```A value of type 'void' can't be returned from function 'sortByDistance' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>'.```

Comment: Oh yeah.. sorry. Sort and then return.

Comment: Now there's an error message ```The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(dirty,
state: _FutureBuilderState<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>#9e3b1):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, just make initial value of `locationListWithDistance` empty, that way we can add to the list and it's not null. `locationListWithDistance = []`

Comment: No still getting the same error. Don't know why.

Comment: try printing the sorted. `print(sorted)` or `print(sorted.toString())`. So we'll know what sorted contains.

Comment: No, nothing gets printed in debug console.

Comment: put the print statement, (try both .toString() and without)  right after that var sorted

Comment: And also as I know the length of list ```locationlist``` I put 4 in place for itembuider but I get error```RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0``` and output for ```print(sorted)``` or ```print(sorted.toString())``` is```I/flutter ( 6140): null```

Comment: please confirm that you have added `List<Map<String, dynamic>> locationListWithDistance = [];`

Comment: https://github.com/Sarthak-source/problems/tree/master

Comment: `if (!snapshot.hasData) {
   return CircularProgressIndicator();
}` Don't remove this condition. or return listView only if `snapshot.hasData` (is `snapshot.hasData` is true, then the sorted list has been returned)

Comment: Yeah but if I don't remove it ```CircularProgressIndicator()``` goes on forever, without rendering required widget. Only when I removed it I got to know there was an error.

Comment: If it goes on for ever then the sorted wasn't returned. Try this, put a `print('new loop')` right after `for (var profile in profilelist)` and print the distance in `distancef` function before returning. this way we'll know when a new loop was started and when the distancef function returned. keep that progress indicator condition.

Comment: New loop is on debug console four times, but```CircularProgressIndicator()``` goes on forever.

Comment: https://github.com/Sarthak-source/problems/issues/1